# Use Arquillian With Port Offset

Tags: wildfly, jboss-arquillian

I have a working Arquillian setup which starts a Wildlfy and runs some tests:

```
<container qualifier="wildfly" default="true">
    <configuration>
        <property name="jbossHome">../target/wildfly-8.1.0.Final/</property>
        <property name="serverConfig">it.xml</property>
    </configuration>
</container>
```

I wanted to change the port-offset of the Wildfly and so added:

```
        <property name="javaVmArguments">-Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=100 -Djboss.management.native.port=9054</property>
        <property name="managementPort">9154</property>
```

Which results in the following exception (both when run it in the IDE and via Maven):

> org.jboss.arquillian.container.spi.client.container.LifecycleException: Could not start container
>   Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Managed server was not started within [60] s

Even though the *server.log* shows clearly that the server was started correctly, and in way under 60s. (And why shouldn't it? It worked before adding the port offset.)

I assume Arquillian is watching the wrong port and is so not able to see the Wildfly being started.

How do make Arquillian aware that the port has changed?

Answer (score 1):

`managementPort` is the right way to make Arquillian aware of the port. The problem is in the `jboss.management.native.port` part. You should be changing `jboss.management.http.port` instead with Wildfly.